# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/home/sarthis7/app.yaml] does not exist

Tags: gcloud

when use gcloud app deploy i am getting following error
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/home/sarthis7/app.yaml] does not exist.

Comment: You're always going to need an `app.yaml` (or similar) to define your app to the service so that it understand what you want to deploy. See: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an `app.yaml` file in the root directory if you want to deploy your app in App Engine

Quoting from the [docs:](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/writing-web-service#creating_the_appyaml_file)

> An app.yaml file specifies settings for your App Engine service's runtime environment. Your service will not deploy without this file.

I suggest checking the [app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) to understand which values you should put in the file.

Also, take a look at the [App Engine quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/quickstart), it may help you understand the whole process of Deploying to App Engine.